# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$ is an ideal of $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In this paper [On prime ideals of Lie algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843), the author proved this theorem:

Let $P$ be an ideal of $L$. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) $P$ is a prime ideal of $L$.

(ii) If $[a,\left\langle b^{L}\right\rangle] \subseteq P$ for $a, b \in L$, then either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.

(iii) If $[a, H] \subseteq P$ for $a \in L$ and an ideal $H$ of $L$, then either $a \in P$ or $H \subseteq P$.

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii). For each $a \in \mathcal{L}$

$$\left\langle a^L \right\rangle= \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i \qquad \textit{where} \qquad V_0 = (a) \qquad \textit{and} \qquad V_i = \big[\ldots\big[(a),\underbrace{L\big],\ldots,}_i\ L\big].$$

My question is I how can prove that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$ is an ideal of $L$ and the smallest ideal containing $a$.

i.e

$$\left\langle a^L \right\rangle= \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$$

> My attempt:

For each $a \in L$, $\langle a^L \rangle$ is defined to be the smallest ideal of $L$ containing $a$. It must contain $a$, and all its scalar multiples, i.e. the $1$-dimensional $F$-vector subspace $(a) := F a \subset \langle a^L \rangle$. But if it contains $(a)$, then (by definition of ideal) it must also contain $[(a),L]$, and hence $[[(a),L],L]$, etc. Because it is a $F$-vector space it must contain their sum.

Therefore, $$\left\langle a^L \right\rangle \supseteq \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$$

Conversely, Let $x \in \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$ and $y \in L$, then $x \in (a)+[(a),L]+[[(a),L],L]+...$.

Thus $[x,y] \in [(a),L]+[[(a),L],L]+...$.

Therefore, $[x,y] \in \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$, hence $\sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$ is an ideal containing $a$, so it contains $\left\langle a^L \right\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of both inclusions looks good to me. To be very precise, one could make it clear that all actual sums in that infinite sum are actually finite, and mention that $\sum V_i$ is (of course) also a sub-vector space, but I would accept it as written.

Comment: Could you explain more please, why the sums in that infinite sum are actually finite?

Comment: What I mean is that by definition, each element $x \in \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i$ is still a *finite* sum i.e. there is a finite set $I_x \subset \mathbb N_0$ such that $x = \sum_{i \in I_x} v_i$ with $v_i \in V_i$, and then $[x,y] \in \sum_{i \in I'_x} V_i \subset \sum_{i =0}^\infty V_i$ where $I'_x = \{i+1 : i \in I_x\}$.

Comment: Is this because the definition is a finite sum?
If $A, B$ are subspaces of $L$, we write $[A, B]$ for the subspace of $L$ generated by the elements of the form $[x, y] (x \in A, y \in B)$.

Comment: Yes, that is basically the definition of any sum $\sum_{i\in I} V_i$ of (sub-)vector spaces (of some big vector space) with finite or infinite index set $I$: elements therein are still finite sums. (Unless one is in a theory where one has a certain convergence coming from a certain metric or topology on the vector space compatible with the ground field ... which is certainly not the setting we are in, in the context here.)